# Add image and title in the same row of the header section of a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I create a shiny dashboard in which I have set `titleWidth` and sidebar width = 0 in order to have them hidden. Then I want to add an image in the left corner of the header section which will completely fit to the header section and then the title in the same row but in the right corner. As you can see now the header section became bigger and also the title seems to be a row lower than the image. Here is my code:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
    titleWidth = "0px",
    tags$li(a(href = 'http://https://www.uow.edu.au/',
              img(src = 'download.png',
                  height = "55px",width="232px"),
              style = "padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right:1690px;padding-left:90px;"),
            class = "dropdown")
    
)
shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPagePlus(
        header = dbHeader,
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px"),
        body = dashboardBody(
            useShinyjs(),
            
            tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
            
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
                '.myClass { 
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding:  1500px;
        padding-bottom: 0 0px;
        padding-top: 0 0px;

        overflow: hidden;
        color: black;
      }
    '))),
            tags$script(HTML('
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("header").find("nav").append(\'<span class="myClass"> Life,Death & Statins </span>\');
      })
     '))
            
            
            
        )
        
    ),
    server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
        hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
        
    }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your are looking for this.  You can play with padding and margins to get appropriate spacing.

```
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death and Statins")

dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",

  tags$li(a(href = "https://www.mit.edu/", #   'http://https://www.uow.edu.au/',
            div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-44px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
                img(src = 'YBS.png', height = "55px",width="232px")),
            div(style="display: inline; padding: 0px 90px 0px 750px ; font-size: 40px ; width: 300px;",HTML(mytitle, "<br>"))
            ),
          class = "dropdown")
)
```

[image: output]

Comment: the image should fit exacly in the header section without gaps in top bottom and left